# Blocking socket communication but not HTTP

Tags: java, sockets, proxy

I'm in a network where I have proxy. My proxy server allowing HTTP communication in any manner but not the socket communication. At the base, I understand HTTP also communicating over socket communication. If I try to create a HTTP communication with socket, by writing raw HTTP request over socket, it is being blocked. Another good example for this is using TCP/IP monitor.

Correct me, if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: If you are using Sockets in your program the Sockets works over HTTP not the other way. If HTTP connection is allowed then your Sockets should also work unless there is some firewall issue.

Comment: @Garry your first sentence does not make sense to me. Using a socket it is possible to send HTTP. The socket does not know about it, for the socket it is just a TCP socket. So it is HTTP that runs on top of the socket. The socket works over TCP.

Comment: @Garry Ya, HTTP communicating over Socket. Reverse is not the case. If firewall issue, how a firewall can identify this is socket/http.

Comment: @PhilipStuyck, So we can say there are 2 way to send a HTTP request 1.Using HTTP protocol, which is totally different from Socket comminication
2.Using TCP protocol, and that's where my proxy refusing to forward it. Is my understanding correct? Sorry for late reply.

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion, it was using TCP in mind. Thanks for making it clear.